# Extract an element value in json using jsonpath

Tags: javascript, jmeter, jsonpath, json-path-expression

Following is my json data

```
{
    "primary": [
        {
            "secondary": {
                "name": {
                    "fullname": "fullname1"
                },
                "alias": "alias1"
            },
            "reference": "reference1"
        },
        {
            "secondary": {
                "name": {
                    "fullname": "fullname2"
                },
                "alias": "alias2"
            },
            "reference": "reference2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to extract "alias" value based on condition based fullname value from this json data using jsonpath.

I am using following expression but failed to parse result

> $.primary[*].secondary[?(@.name.fullname == "fullname1")].alias

Comment: Your JSON doesn't parse.

Comment: @Andy updated with valid json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is malformed, if it really looks like you posted - you won't be able to use JSON Extractor, you will have to switch to [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor).

Valid JSON would be something like:

```
{
  "primary": [
    {
      "secondary": {
        "name": {
          "fullname": "fullname1"
        },
        "alias": "alias1"
      },
      "reference": "reference1"
    },
    {
      "secondary": {
        "name": {
          "fullname": "fullname2"
        },
        "alias": "alias2"
      },
      "reference": "reference2"
    },
    {
      "type": "online"
    }
  ]
}
```

And if it is correct your [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) expression works fine as it evidenced by [JsonPath Tester mode of the View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/):

[image]

Comment: I am getting following error when running `Exception: Could not compile inline filter : [?(@.name.fullname == "fullname1")]`